# How to implement the win7 aero effect when I use a customized titlebar?

Tags: qt4

for my application, I use the customized titlebar(minimize,maximize,close), and disalbe the system titlebar, then when I run my application in win7, I can not make the application maximium when drag the application to top screen.

Comment: It seems to be not that simple. Disabling the standart title bar is not recommended. You will have to use WinAPI to make your custom title bar.